# is possible work with 2 schedule with the same Timer

Tags: java, android

**Can I do this ? is possible work with 2 schedule with the same Timer ?**

```
Long period = 10000L;

Timer timer = new Timer(); 

timer.schedule(new Mytask_1(this), 0, period);

timer.schedule(new Mytask_2(this), 0, period);
```

any help is appreciated!

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can. But keep in mind that *Timer object is a single background thread that is used to execute all of the timer's tasks, sequentially. Timer tasks should complete quickly. If a timer task takes excessive time to complete, it "hogs" the timer's task execution thread. This can, in turn, delay the execution of subsequent tasks, which may "bunch up" and execute in rapid succession when (and if) the offending task finally completes.*

Note that since Java 1.5 there is no reason to use Timer, use java.util.concurrent package schedulers instead. From ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor API:

*This class is preferable to Timer when multiple worker threads are needed...*